# How to sort a random array of points into a shape?

Tags: python, point-clouds

I have a random array of points that forms a shape like this:

[image]

But it comes in such a way that the points (coordinates) that make it up are randomly distributed in an array.

How do I sort them so they are continuous (every pair of consecutive points in the array corresponds to a pair of consecutive points in the shape)?

Edit: should've explained it better.

We tried using some sort of clockwise-ness of the points, but it breaks at the edges and at the straight lines in the back.
Some sort of seed, where the lowest X point is the starting point, and the closest ones get appended to it. Also breaks at the edges, where the closest point isn't necessary the consecutive one.
If I separate upper and lower (using the lowest X point as the Y-criteria), and sort both arrays separately, the concave part breaks this as well.

The points come in a .dat file, where each line is 2 numbers, separated by a space:

```
2.345 1.234
1.234 2.345
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is a "point"? A 2-tuple? A custom data structure? A library-specific class?

Comment: How did you generate these points in the first place?

Comment: Can one assume that given 3 continuous points A, B, C then it does not exist a point X such that the distance between B and X is smaller than the distance between A and B and the distance between B and C?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych edited to add explanation

Comment: @Fractalism edited the main post. These points represent the surface of the cross section of a structure.

Comment: It breaks at the edges because the array does not have enough information about the shape. Kinda... If it breaks and places points in the wrong order, it's only you thinking it's the incorrect one, but it's still a shape, just a different shape. Seems like it cannot be done in an universal manner. You can use some heuristics here, but it won't be accurate in 100% cases.

Comment: As it stands, it's impossible to answer your question, because it lacks explanations on how you would recognise the shape. If you have a list of points, you can sort them in clockwise order, or in some other order, or in some other order, and every different order will give you a different shape. You state in your question that clockwise order does not result in the wanted shape. But how do you know which shape you want? Please explain.

Comment: @Stef I KNOW the shape the points should make. The points were extracted from it, I just need to sort them back in their original position, such that if I plot them (or something equivalent that takes into account the fact they're consecutive) they recreate the original shape, not something resembling a random walk).

Comment: What do you mean by "know" the shape? You had a data structure in memory that represented that shape? What does this data structure look like? How did you extract the points from this data structure?

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for a [registration algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-set_registration) between the sets of extracted points and "the shape", but if you don't tell us more about what exactly you know about this shape, we can't help.

Comment: Oh, you changed the picture! It looks much simpler now. It looks like a simple traveling salesman would solve the problem: find the order that minimizes the sum of distances of "adjacent" points.

Comment: @Stef I, person, know how it should look like. The software in which this shape is stored can only export (and we can only use) the data as points. The computer doesn't know the shape, it only sees points. I want it to make the shape. Edited the original post for clarification.

Comment: Yeah, so, with your edit it looks much easier. Each point mostly wants to be adjacent to the closest points.

Comment: How about start with an arbitrary point, then enter a loop in which you continually pop the current point from the list and move on to the closest point?

Comment: Have fun with this: [The traveling salesman problem in 10 lines of python](https://ericphanson.com/blog/2016/the-traveling-salesman-and-10-lines-of-python/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/52627 you can use a part of Grahm Scan convex hull algorithm.

> The first step of the Grahm Scan is to sort the points in a set based on the angle made with the X axis when drawing a line through the point and the lower-right point of the set.

> If two or more points form the same angle with the X axis (i.e. are aligned with respect to the reference point) then those points should be sorted based on distance from the reference point.

```
import dataclasses
from functools import cmp_to_key


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float


def left_(p: Point, a: Point, b: Point) -> float:
    return (a.x - p.x) * (b.y - p.y) - (b.x - p.x) * (a.y - p.y)


def compare_angle(p: Point, a: Point, b: Point) -> float:
    left = left_(p, a, b)
    if left == 0:
        return compare_distance(p, a, b)
    return left


def compare_distance(p: Point, a: Point, b: Point) -> float:
    distance_a = (p.x - a.x) ** 2 + (p.y - a.y) ** 2
    distance_b = (p.x - b.x) ** 2 + (p.y - b.y) ** 2
    return distance_a - distance_b


def sort_points(points: list[Point]):
    y0 = min(map(lambda p: p.y, points))
    p0 = Point(
        y=y0,
        x=max(map(lambda p: p.x, filter(lambda p: p.y == y0, points)))
    )
    return sorted(points, key=cmp_to_key(lambda a, b: compare_angle(p0, a, b)))
```

Although, it still has some limitations, so possibly it won't make it perfectly in 100% cases, as shapes may be too complex. I think, it will do the work with even points distribution and when there is a decent amount of point comparing to the shape size, but if there will be some complex shape with long-running edges between points, close calls between the shape parts etc., it may make mistakes.

P.S.: what I mean when I say in the comments that the computer does not know the correct shape so it can be wrong:

both are the same points and both are mathematically correct non-self intersecting polygons
[image: example]

Comment: I get what you mean. But the points are way too dense for it to guess incorrectly, it's just a matter of connect the dots but with thousands of them making an almost perfect shape, just randomly arranged. Also, the line def sort_points(points: list[Point]): returns the error TypeError: 'Type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @LucasPelizzari It should probably be `List[Point]` with a capital L

Comment: @LucasPelizzari yep, the older Python versions do not support type annotations with types itself. Import List from typing and use it